# How to rewrite correctly url htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would know how to rewrite a multilanguae website the url ?

When the rewrite configuration is not applied I have this url

```
boutique/index.php (default language en)
boutique/index.php?language=fr
boutique/index.php?Products&Description&products_id=20
```

When the rewrite configuration is applied I have this url

```
boutique/index.php (default language en)
boutique/index.php/language,en
boutique/index.php/language,fr

boutique/index.php/Products/Description/products_id,20
```

I tried this but not work.

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.php  /$2.php/language=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: "I tried this but it's not working" is not a proper problem statement. What url are you going to and what exactly is the error?